# Get input binded value in reactive form (Angular)

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

I have a reactive form field that has a value based on other inputs.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [value]="isStrongEnough" formControlName="secret"/>
```

How can I get this value (live)?  When I try the below it comes back empty, even though the field has a value showing (i.e., true/false)

```
{{ form.get('secret').value }}
```

Comment: Is `form` the name of your primary FormGroup? So your `<form` tag includes binding like this: `[formGroup]="form"`?

Comment: @DeborahK.  Yes. It is.  I can also get the results of all other fields

Comment: Can you show the component code where you define the `FormGroup`?